# C++ ofstream float encode

Tags: c++, floating-point, 32-bit, ieee-754, ofstream

does anyone knows how to write an IEEE 754 single-precision (32-bit) floating-point number to an ofstream?

i'm using:

```
float VERSION = 0.1;
ofstream header;
header.open("a4.pbf",ios::binary);
header.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&VERSION), sizeof(float));
header.close();
```

- the result value:   "0xCD,0xCC,0xCC,0x3D"
- the value expected: "0x3D,0xCC,0xCC,0xCD"

thanks.

Comment: Why did you actually expect `"0x3D,0xCC,0xCC,0xCD"`? There's a numerous reasons, why you can't rely on this. You know everything about [_endianess_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), don't you?

Comment: i'm changing the main code in actionscript3 to C++, and don't want to drop compatibility:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#writeFloat

Comment: how can i set the endian of ofstream in c++?

Comment: The question on how to set the endianess of a stream doesn't make any sense at all. Also, whenever you write data to a file you'll be best off to abstract the operation so you know the format of the data (and, yes, that makes sense even if the transformation happens to be the identity on some systems; obviously in your case it isn't because you need to encode the data to use the appropriate endianess).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the question doesn't need improvement, it's perfectly well stated. You're the one who asked for justification for the question.

Comment: @RenanMuniz The "endianness of the stream" doesn't make much sense in this context. You're writing the bytes out in precisely the order they are stored in memory, the byte order in your output will depend on the endianness of floats on the underlying platform. It doesn't actually *matter* what order they are written to the output *as long as that order is consistent in the output between all platforms*. Otherwise you'll have trouble transferring saved data files between platforms. Reinterpreting to a 32-bit unsigned int and using `htonl` and `ntohl` is an easy way to guarantee order in output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can convert the `float` to a `uint32_t`, you can use [`htonl`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) to get "network" byte order which is big-endian.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest when this popped up in the queue. This will guarantee the same byte order in the stored data regardless of the platform's local ordering, as long as the float can fit in 32 bits (as in the OP's case). Note the inverse is `ntohl`, when reading.